# Angular JS not updating ng-bind values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i want to start out saying that i am a very novice angular.js developer only working with it for about 2 months, making basic test apps. Now i got my first small project that i am implementing and i can across a problem.

**The problem** is i have 2 set of variable that i am updating from a controller. These variable are being changed from a callback function so angular does not know they changed. I have read that if a variable is changed outside of angular context the View will not be updated.

The second issue is that i am using the **controller As** method to initialize the controller, as i understand this is the way to make controllers **(best practice)**. With this type of controller initialization i do not have access to the **$scope**.

The solution: would this need to be implemented as directive to achieve what i am trying to do or some other pattern?

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="container-fluid navbar-fixed-top text-center" ng-controller="geoloc as GCController">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            {{GCController.lat}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            {{GCController.lon}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Angular Controller File**

```
angular
    .module('geoapp')
    .controller('geoloc', geoloc);

geoloc.$inject = [];

/* @ngInject */
function geoloc() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.activate = activate;
    vm.title = 'geoloc';
    vm.lat = 0;
    vm.lon = 0;
    vm.error = false;

    test = 0;
    activate();

    ////////////////

    function activate() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                console.log("Setting" + position.coords.latitude + " " + position.coords.longitude);
                vm.lat = position.coords.latitude;
                vm.lon = position.coords.longitude;
            });
        }
        else {
            vm.error = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you paste your code ?

Comment: check this article on Angularjs digest cycle http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/